# Javadoc: error - Cannot find doclet class

Tags: javadoc

I'm trying to run Javadoc with a custom doclet from windows command line:

```
javadoc -classpath C:\path\to\build\dir -sourcepath C:\path\to\src\dir -doclet somePackageName.customDocletClassFileName anotherPackageName
```

"anotherPackageName" is the package directly under given sourcepath for which I want to produce documentation.

When I execute it like this I get the error:

```
javadoc: error - Cannot find doclet class somePackageName.customDocletClassFileName
```

It seems like there is something wrong with the -classpath flag, any ideas?

If I substitute

```
-doclet somePackageName.customDocletClassFileName
```

to

```
-docletpath somePackageName
```

it works better (although I cannot really verify the output since I have not added the testng jar to the classpath and then there's a lot of other issues).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SOLUTION:

-classpath is not used for finding doclets, instead -docletpath should be used, i.e:

```
javadoc -classpath C:\path\to\build\dir -docletpath C:\path\to\build\dir -sourcepath C:\path\to\src\dir -doclet somePackageName.customDocletClassFileName anotherPackageName
```

(Thanks to a colleague)

Comment: `C:\path\to\build\dir` is that the directory  which contains the .class file (i.e. customDocletClassFileName.class)